# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not working in the iOS simulator

Tags: ios

I have used the following code, but the when I run the program, swipe isn't working.

First I added gesture recognizer protocol in the interface section

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BNRViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *swipe;

@end
```

Now I instantiated swipe gesture recogniser in the implement section

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fingerSwipe:)];

    swipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 3;
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

}
```

can any one help me out

Comment: How do you simulate  a 3 finger touch in the simulator? (`swipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 3`)

Comment: what you want move your label? or click on label?

Comment: You forgot to set your target and action.

Comment: I was just checking how to perform swipe gesture,since I was facing difficulty in a program, where I have bring a colour panel, when I swipe with three fingers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gesture recognizer won't work unless you set **userInteractionEnabled to YES** on the label.
so you must add this line `[swipe setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` it is working i have checked.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fingerSwipe:)];

[swipe setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

swipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
```

Comment: Thanks you, this worked, actually I copied this from a document, because I was facing difficulty in my own program,using swipe gesture.

Answer (score 0):

there might be defined more than 1 gesture for the view

you can check with this;

```
self.view.gestureRecognizers.count
```

remove all gestures and add your swipe gesture then try again

```
self.view.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer)
```